# Unable to reset the MySQL root password on a Mac

Tags: mysql, macos, passwords

I just reinstalled MySQL using brew on my mac.
As far as I can see everything works fine, but I cannot change my root password.

*When trying I'm getting this **error message**:*

```
mysql -u root
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

The common way to solve this seems to use (several answers on stack overflow suggest using this):

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
2017-05-19T11:54:35.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/var/mysql/mac.err'.
2017-05-19T11:54:35.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
2017-05-19T11:54:35.6NZ mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/mysql/mac.pid ended
```

I stopped the server before executing the command. But this solution does not work for me.

There is also no entry in the **error log**:

```
/usr/local/var/mysql/mac.err
```

I read also about using `mysql_secure_installation` but there I get just the same error message as when using `mysql -u root`.

As I mentioned above, I tried already to just uninstall and reinstall it again, but obviously some data remained. So is there maybe any way to manually delete or reset these files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Solution by OP.*

It turned out that:

```
mysql.server start --skip-grant-tables
```

(not sure if `sudo` is necessary)

works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The access denied is because you're not specifying the -p switch
If you know the old password then maybe login to MySql and change it as:
   1).login to MySql 2).change to the correct db 3) change the passwd and flush

```
mysql -u root -p
mysql> use mysql;
mysql> update user set password=PASSWORD("newpass") where User='ENTER-USER-NAME-HERE';
```

mysql> flush privileges;
   mysql> quit

Also, the following works in Linux/Unix systems but i haven't tested it on Mac (may work if you have the clients installed)

```
mysqladmin -u root -p oldpassword newpass
```

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html

//If you don't remember the password, to recover it check this out(bottom).

https://www.howtoforge.com/setting-changing-resetting-mysql-root-passwords

https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/how-to-change-the-mysql-root-password/

Comment: It has been a longer time ago I used the server, so I unfortunately have no idea what the password was.. 
You don't have any suggestion how to reset the password without knowing the old one?
Thanks for your answer!

Comment: i updated the answer. There are some good instructions to recover mysql root pass

Comment: Unfortunately these links suggest using ´mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables´ which for some reason does not work for me.. But thanks nevertheless!

Comment: did you stop the service? what error are you getting

Comment: It's written in the question above :-)
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
2017-05-19T11:54:35.6NZ mysqld_saf....